# CSS animation stops working when i add foreground to DOM

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

[image]

Hi i'm inside a react app, and have an animation that i like and it works good, about is an image of the animation when the cursor is hovered on a specific hexagon.
But when i render anything else to the dom it doesnt work, the foreground elements block the background animations, anyone have a solution? I've tried updating the jsx file and css cant figure it out.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";  
import './Background.css'   

const HexBG = () => {
    const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
    const rows = 15;
    const hexagonsPerRow = 20;
    
    return (
        <div className="hexagon-container">
            <div className="background">
                <body id="body" className="body">
                    <div className="container">
                        {Array(rows).fill().map((_, rowIndex) => (
                            <div key={rowIndex} className="row">
                                {Array(hexagonsPerRow).fill().map((_, hexagonIndex) => (
                                    <div key={hexagonIndex} 
                                        className={`hexagon ${isHover ? "hexagon-hover" : ""}`}
                                        onMouseOver={() => setIsHover(true)}
                                        onMouseOut={() => setIsHover(false)}>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </body>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default HexBG;
```

here is my css

```
.hexagon-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:9999999;
  }
.BG{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}  

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



body {
    background-color: black;
}

.row {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: -32px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}


.row:nth-child(even) {

    margin-left: 2px;
}


.hexagon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 110px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: rgb(59, 57, 57);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
    animation: animation 14s linear infinite;
    transition: 1s;
}

.hexagon:hover{
    background-color: rgb(0, 245, 20);
    transition: 0s;
}


@keyframes animation {
    0% {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.hexagon:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top : 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(54, 53, 53);
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}

.hexagon:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.3);
    z-index: 2;
}

.foreground-element {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

id appreciate any insights. thanks

Comment: What do you want happen? By definition, "foreground" elements are above things in the "background". What is the visual result you have now and how do you want it to look? Screenshots would help.

Comment: I've added a photo of the animation when nothing is rendered on top

Comment: You have some HTML DOM structure issues. `<body>` can never be enclosed by a `<div>`. It has to be a direct descendent of the top level `<HTML>` tag. Likely this is a duplicate body. You can indeed get very odd stuff happening if you provide the browser with invalid HTML. Change `<body id="body" className="body">` to a div.